# Split Bipartite Graph

Tags: graphs, partitions, bipartite-graph

I have a bipartite graph $G=(U=\{U_1, U_2,\cdots\}, V=\{V_1, V_2,\cdots\} , E)$ such that edges don't "skip" the $V$ vertices. Meaning, if edge $(U_i, V_j)$ doesn't exist, neither will edges $(U_i, V_k)$ for all $k>j$. All vertices connected to $U_1$ are at the "first" $V_i$s, and all vertices connected to the last $U_n$ are the "last" $V_i$s.

Also of note, there are **much** more vertices in $V$ than in $U$ ($|U| \ll |V|$).

I'm looking for a way to split $U$ to disjoint subsets ("Blocks") such that:

- Each subset contains contiguous vertices (if both $U_i$ and $U_{i+j}$ are in block $B$, then $U_{i+k} \in B$ for all $1\lt k\lt j$)
- Each Block has size between $m$ and $M$, where $M<|U|$.
- Minimal number of "split $V_i$s" - a vertex $V_i$ connected to $U_s$ and $U_t$ that belong to different blocks $B_x$ and $B_y$.

Is there some way to find such a partitioning?

Comment: Can you split $U$ into just one block?

Comment: If the size of *U* were in the interval *[m, M]* then yes, but if it's larger than M (which is the interesting case), obviously no.